# **DOJO** WidgetList and InlineTemplate is really slow when

Tags: performance, widget, dojo

I am having an issue with one of my custom dojo widgets.

I am using an MVC structure to build my widget and I am also using dojo's dojox/mvc functionality.

I have a template that has a WidgetList and inside an InlineTemplate.

My problem is that it's very slow when the store has more that 50 items inside.

It sometimes takes 15 seconds to display the rendered data on the screen.

Does anyone ever had that problem and if so how did you solve it?

If you need more information please ask me.

**EDIT :**

This is the template with the WidgetList and the InlineTemplate:

Please let me know if you see something that should not be here!

```
<div>
<script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid" id="flaggedWidgetList2">
        <div>
            <h3>Test 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
            data-dojo.attach-point="flaggedPoint"
            data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
            data-dojo-props="children: at(this.controller.model.listItems, 'Items')">
            <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
               <div class="row-fluid" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'notRead'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'cssClass'}">
                <div class="row-fluid itemRow">
                    <div class="span1" style="float: left;">
                        <input class="span3" type="checkbox" style="float: left;" />
                        <span class="dateRecieved span9" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'DateReceived'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1" style="float: left;">
                        <span class="span12" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'PriorityFlag'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span10" style="float: left;">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <span class="from span3" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Sender'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                            <span class="docId span1 offset8" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'AttachmentNumber'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <span class="title span12" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Title'), id: at('rel:', 'WobNum'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <span class="span3" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'AttachmentType'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b>[]</b></span>
                            <span class="deadline span1 offset8" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Deadline'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                     <div class="span10 offset2" data-dojo-type="DTWidgets/ActionsMenu/ActionMenu" data-dojo-attach-point="itemId" data-dojo-props="itemId: at('rel:', 'WobNum'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'itemId'}"">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Solon

Comment: Take careful timings and work out what is taking up the time, then post that code.

Comment: @PaulGrime I tried doing that with IE9 "Profile" and "Network" in the developer tools (i cannot use any other browser for now due to cross domain web service calls) and i only see a waiting time from an unspecified source. I will edit the post above to show the template and if you see anything that might cause this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: based on the way my widget is build (MVC) i cannot do a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

`dojox/mvc/WidgetList` is based on [`dijit/_Container`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_Container.html), and the addition of child is done via its `addChild()`, which uses [`domConstruct.place()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-construct.html#place). When the child is based on [`dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html), which is the case as `dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin` is in use, [`dojo/parser`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html) runs against every child to instantiate the widgets in the template.

I think those two are the major parts considering performance of `dojox/mvc/WidgetList`. The former (call to `addChild()`) is done [in `dojox/mvc/WidgetList` code](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/dojox/trunk/mvc/WidgetList.js#L257) and the latter (instantiating widgets in template) is done [in `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` code](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/dijit/trunk/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.js#L45), so you may want closer look at how long each iteration of them takes, for example with [`performance.now()` API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html#domhighrestimestamp), etc. Depending on the case, digging deeper may be needed, for example, with [Chrome Developer Tool's timeline panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline).

Below code may help as a starter, though it didn't take long time to render child widgets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
            @import "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" 
            data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 0, async: 1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dojo/when",
                "dojo/Stateful",
                "dojox/mvc/StatefulArray",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(array, parser, when, Stateful, StatefulArray){
                model = new Stateful({items: []});
                when(parser.parse(), function(){
                    model.set("items", new StatefulArray(array.map(new Array(50), function(){
                        return new Stateful({
                            notRead: 1,
                            cssClass: "cssClass",
                            DateReceived: "DateReceived",
                            PriorityFlag: 1,
                            Sender: "Sender",
                            AttachmentNumber: 1,
                            Title: "Title",
                            WobNum: 1,
                            AttachmentType: "AttachmentType",
                            Deadline: "Deadline"
                        });
                    })));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
                    data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
                    data-dojo-props="children: at(model, 'items'), partialRebuild: 1">
                    <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
                        <div>
                            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'notRead'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'cssClass'}">
                            <div> 
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" />
                                    <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'DateReceived'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'PriorityFlag'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Sender'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                                        <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'AttachmentNumber'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Title'), id: at('rel:', 'WobNum'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'AttachmentType'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b>[]</b></span>
                                        <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Deadline'), _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}"><b></b></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope those help.

Best,
Akira